# Getting sum of values from Dicts in a List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
order = [{"name": 'espresso', "price": 1.99},
         {"name": 'coffee', "price": 2.50},
         {"name": 'cake', "price": 2.79},
         {"name": 'soup', "price": 4.50},
         {"name": 'sandwich', "price": 4.99}]
```

I need to get the sum of the `order` and put that sum in a variable called `subtotal`. I understand I need a for loop through the list but don't know how to grab the value associated with `"price"` in each `dict` and sum them all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square brackets to get the price:

```py
# Prints out all the prices
for x in order:
    print(x['price'])
```

Now, all you have to do is add this to a variable called `subtotal`

```py
# Adds prices to subtotal and outputs 16.77
subtotal = 0.0
for x in order:
    subtotal += x['price']
print(subtotal)
```

Or, more simply:

```py
# Uses a comprehension along with sum (again outputs 16.77)
subtotal = sum(x['price'] for x in order)
print(subtotal)
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else! This has helped. Several of the solutions work, but this helped me understand the best. For some reason I was stuck on thinking it had to be nested for loops..

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using square brackets and the `iadd` operation (+=):

```
subtotal = 0
for x in price:
    subtotal += x["price"]
```

A faster way of accomplishing that would also be to use the `sum` function and using a generator comprehension that is faster as suggested in the comments by @b.d:

```
subtotal = sum(x["price"] for x in price)
```

#### on other answers

I saw this by @JudeDavis the answers one who does it also using list comprehension:

```
subtotal = sum([x["price"] for x in price])
```

it's literally the same thing as the code provided above but by interpreter optimizations the generator comprehension is faster
long story short, the list has 2 features:

- mutable
- supports non-unique items

but the tuple supports only non-unique items so it's a little bit faster with some optimization done by python(not getting into details).

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `sum` function to sum the list, and we create the list using list comprehension.

```
subtotal = sum([d["price"] for d in order])
```

Good day.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `sum` function to sum it up.

But instead of summing over a list, use a **generator** instead for optimized code.

```
subtotal = sum(d["price"] for d in order)
```

PS: Notice that the sum function is not performed on a list *(and is a generator instead)* like in the answer provided by @JudeDavis